# Converting Spring MVC to Spring Boot app. Is it feasible and worth it?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, migration

Also, any suggestions plz on how to start on this?

My Spring MVC application is only a backend service with no front end screen.
I need to connect to  Database and OAuth service in the backend in my application.

Comment: Spring Boot == Spring MVC + autoconfiguration. So you aren't moving to Spring Boot you are just adding it.

Comment: I agree with you Deinum. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are many parts missing (from MVC to boot), I'd recommend to create an empty boot project and fill in the mvc parts in the proper place. I could also recommend to use the Jhipster for generating a full spring boot boilerplate!

Comment: Thanks RoxcH for your response! 
How about if I remove the Spring Framework dependencies from my project and add the Spring boot main class.
Do you think it can be a solution to this? Just trying to implement the same...

Comment: Not having seen the size and details of your current project, I'd say it can become a mess, unless you're an expert in each line of Spring…